# Debug Visualizer use member method / function call in preview?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, native, debuggervisualizer

Using Visual Studio 2010 with native C++.  When editing autoexp.dat, is it possible to use the results of a method call in a debug visualizer preview?

For example, if my class is Person how can I do something like:

```
MyNamespace::Person{
  preview(
    #("FirstName=", $e->GetFirstName())
  )
}
```

(You may ask why I don't just get the private member variable data and that is because GetFirstName() delegates to a 3rd party library method call, so I do not have access to the data member.  Another reason could be the method performs some calculation.)

Comment: And what happens if you view instance of MyNamespace::Person in debugger? Do you see its data members or is this some kind of hidden implementation (e.g. Pimpl idiom)?

Comment: @gwiazdorrr: if I have a local Person class variable called "person" and I hover over it with the mouse the tooltip that appears shows: "person = 0x0675ca00 {3rdPartyPointer_=0x0c38b780 }".   I can expand the plus sign 2 or 3 levels and there just a few memory addresses.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at the following:

- https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/boost_docs/subprojects/DebuggerVisualizers/boost__DateTime.msvc8.vis.txt
- https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/boost_docs/subprojects/DebuggerVisualizers/date_time_visualizer.hpp

See comments about user custom functions here for some people's experience with this:

- http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=120

Answer (score 1):

No the Visual Studio debugger only supports directly reading virtual memory. Supporting e->GetFirstName() would require doing introspection into the GetFirstName() function, which could be very complicated if GetFirstName() is non-trivial or virtual (worse yet GetFirstName() could have side-effects or crash). Changing autoexp.dat won't let you get around this problem.

If you really want to get this functionality, you could add a new debug-only member function like std::string *_firstName and point it to GetFirstName() on construction of Person, then have autoexp.dat dereference and display this variable for you.

Comment: I guess you meant "... add a new debug-only member *variable* like std::string...".  I've thought about this but it seems a little kludgy.   However, I'm guessing you're right that there is no way to call a function.

Comment: In fact, from the watch window you can actually call debuggee functions and do crazy stuff, not only read memory. Not sure about autoexp.dat, though.